# How to sed pattern matching and stop after the last match

Tags: sed

I have a huge log file that could repet values over and over. i want to grep a set like Word A to Word D but stop after a match. in the below, it starts over again.

```
sed -n -e '/Word A/,/Word D/ p'
```

How can you get it to stop after finding the first "Word D"

```
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word D
Word E
Word F
Word D
Word G
```

Expected result with sed -n -e '/Word A/,/Word D/ p'

```
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word D
```

Actual result:

```
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word D
Word E -> should not exist
Word F -> should not exist
Word D -> should not exist
Word G -> should not exist
```

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using. There are many different implementations of `sed` so some might behave as you describe.

Comment: oh, btw, fix your title - you want to stop after the 1st match, don't you ?

Comment: OK, then it's probably Windows line endings as you suggested @don_crissti.

Comment: It is not a CRLF issue. I've tested it on the data converted to both DOS and Mac newlines... The `sed` command on the DOS file does the right thing, while there's no output when running on a file with Mac newlines. @don_crissti

Answer (score 1):

Unable to replicate with GNU `sed` 4.2.2:

```
home:~/scratch/
$ sed -ne '/Word A/,/Word D/p' input
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word D
home:~/scratch/
$ cat input
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word D
Word E
Word F
Word D
Word G
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this with OpenBSD's `sed` nor with GNU `sed`.

If the data had been

```
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word D
Word E
Word F
Word A
Word D
Word G
```

(note the extra `Word A` line)

```
$ sed -n -e '/Word A/,/Word D/p' data.in
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word D
Word A
Word D
```

If you only wanted the first bit of that output:

```
$ sed -n -e '/Word A/,/Word D/p' -e '/Word D/q' data.in
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word D
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue was with a incorrect escape char. Thanks for the tips all

```
for /f "tokens=* " %%e in ('sed -n "/\/ios\/mdm2\/%Perimeter%.*DEBUG MDM payload/,/<\/plist>/p" %log%') do ( echo %%e > file.txt)
```

Comment: Sorry, but your answer doesn't put any light on the problem. I don't see any relation to the original question.